# Biopython fail to access hetero-residue directly

Tags: biopython

I am able to access directly a residue from the protein 1n31 by using:

```
residue = structure[0]['A'][100]
```

However, when I try to access a hetero-residue, like:

```
residue = structure[0]['A'][2003]
```

I get the error message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

File "/home/azevedo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Chain.py", line 94, in __getitem__
return Entity.__getitem__(self, id)

File "/home/azevedo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Entity.py", line 41, in __getitem__
return self.child_dict[id]
```

> KeyError: (' ', 2003, ' ')

Why is it happening? How can I directly access a hetero-residue?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

```
structure[0]['A'][('H_CYS', 2003, ' ')]
```

will give you the desired residue

```
<Residue CYS het=H_CYS resseq=2003 icode= >
```

**BioPython's PDB indexes**

BioPython's PDB residue index uses a `tuple` internally. It consists of hetero flag, sequence identifier and insertion code. For your residue 1000 it would be (' ', 100, ' '), in case of your hetero-residue it would be `('H_CYS', 2003, ' ')`.

If you provide only an integer as an index it gets translated to `(' ', your_int, ' ')`.

The code can be found in the function [`_translate_id`](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/Chain.py)

**General solution**

If you don't know the hetero flag in advance, you could use your own function

```
def get_residue_by_number(residues, number):
    for residue in residues:
        if residue.id[1] == number:
            return residue

get_residue_by_number(structure[0]['A'].get_residues(), 2003)
```

> ```
> <Residue CYS het=H_CYS resseq=2003 icode= >
> ```

```
get_residue_by_number(structure[0]['A'].get_residues(), 100)
```

> ```
> <Residue ASP het=  resseq=100 icode= >
> ```