# Error occurred while selecting a specific atom in a PDB file using Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

The following is a partial content of my PDB file. I want to set the C2 atom as the coordinate origin, but the code shows an error.

```
HETATM    1  C1  UNL A  1      -2.791  -1.310   0.787  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    2  C2  UNL A  1      -3.711  -0.441   0.007  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    3  C3  UNL A  1      -3.059   0.725  -0.664  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    4  C4  UNL A  1      -2.098   1.359   0.308  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    5  C5  UNL A  1      -1.114   0.285   0.724  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    6  O1  UNL A  1      -1.813  -0.636   1.488  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM    7  O2  UNL A  1      -0.433  -0.261  -0.324  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM    8  C6  UNL A  1       0.922  -0.022  -0.191  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    9  C7  UNL A  1       1.725  -1.297  -0.057  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   10  C8  UNL A  1       3.160  -0.900   0.201  1.00  0.00           C
```

the code is,

```
import numpy as np
import residue as residue
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

parser = PDBParser()
structure = parser.get_structure('CEL', 'cel.pdb')
origin = structure[0]['A'][1]
```

KeyError: (' ', 1, ' ')

Answer (score 0):

its the way Bio.PDB.PDBParser works see:

[Biopython fail to access hetero-residue directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429515/biopython-fail-to-access-hetero-residue-directly)

try:

```
import numpy as np
#import residue as residue
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser

parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE='True', QUIET='True')


structure = parser.get_structure('CEL', 'cel.pdb')

origin = structure[0]['A']['H_UNL', 1 , ' ']

print(origin)
```

output:

```
<Residue UNL het=H_UNL resseq=1 icode= >
```